# How to disable the SAP copyright popup for users logging on for the first time?

Tags: ui-automation, sap-gui

I'm load-testing SAP ERP(on hana) with rational performance tester.

As the copyright popup after the first SAP logon interferes with my test runs (1000 sap test-users of type service), I have to disable the notification for all these users, or system-wide.

I tried to set the last logon date from a default to a valid date but somehow the system still knows that its the user's first logon. How can I disable the notification?

Comment: This popup is not only for the first logon. It is also shown when you log in in a different language than the one used during the previous logon. Thus I do not think it can be disabled as it shows terms of use.

Comment: On the second thought maybe there is a field called last logon language you could use together with last logon date?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it is not possible to disable the copyright notifications on first logon or logon with a new language.

However, the problem i was facing can be handled by recording a RPT test, where you only press the continue button of the copyright notification after the logon and then close the session (stop recording). Then you substitute the logon username with a datapool of all users you want to use and run the test against the system with the proper amount of virtual users. As long as you don't change the language every user should be free from the copyright popup in the future.